# How to snap an object onto a face of another object?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I have a pentagon with a square inside of it with a very specific position inside the pentagon.

I need to duplicate the pentagon 12 times and snap it into faces of a dodecahedron, which is a solid made up of 12 pentagon (ngon) faces:
[image]

How can I do this?
In my image above the way I've done it is turned the pentagon with the square inside it into an image and applied it as a texture on the dodecahedron to use as a visual guide for modelling the squares by hand. Due to texture filtering imperfections and manual nature the results have not been very accurate at all.

Can the placement of the pentagon+square on a specific pentagon face of the dodecahedron be done automatically, for example via snapping? The pentagon+square will need to share both the position and rotation of the penatgon face of the dodecahedron.

Thanks.

PS. This is a simplified example of the problem, before you ask why anybody would want to perfectly position a square like this. The square is actually a fiducial marker and we are using Blender to create simulated camera videos for a OpenCV machine vision project to exclude any issues arising from real world camera imperfections from our tests.

Comment: Sounds like the job for duplifaces, though I'm almost positive rotations will not by default have the expected rotations and will likely require manual adjustment

Comment: duplifaces are gone in 2.8

Comment: No they are not, just renamed to instancing

Comment: arguing schemantics, we have no way to guess what the new name of a feature is