# How to realize Geometry Nodes instances and boolean here

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

Here's an [answer to a question I posted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242521/how-to-intrude-extrude-a-cube-or-other-irregular-shape-knife-tool-onto-a-un/244912) (It's down in the comments)

Derived from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WRPqpIuMt0)

[Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/ac680d5fc7e740f58c835b510628a5dc)

The only thing missing is the ability to Boolean the spheres, cubes, cylinders.

I think that involves realizing instances via the Realize Instances node, but, it's not covered in the tutorial, and nothing I've tried works.

This is what it looks like before and after attempting to apply a boolean Difference.

[image: Dodecahedron with Sphere faces - by Geometry Nodes - See Download]

This is me attempting to apply a boolean (Difference)

[image: Attempting to apply a Boolean modifier - "Difference"]

What it should look like if it worked (imagine it all around) instead of just the top face:

[image: Single sphere Boolean - manually applied - NOT Geometry Nodes]

Comment: what do you mean by "boolean the spheres!?" -> i think because this isn't clear you aren't getting answers here. Best is often to include screenshots how it should look like.

Comment: I did include the blend file.  The objects:  sphere, cylinder, or cube are intruded into the dodecahedron, but, won't boolean (Difference) because they're not realized mesh.  Any attempts to cause them to disappear.  Download the file and try it yourself to get a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if i understood it right, you want this:

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Here's what I tried.  It didn't work:  https://imgur.com/a/QGhKkzE - Something you're doing that I'm not.  There's a rest of the story that's missing.

Comment: just rebuild my node tree...as i showed in the answer

Comment: Figured it out.  Fixed it.  Nevermind.  Problem was in the Join Geometry connections.  Deleted and reconneccted Join Geometry as shown in your example.

Comment: Checked and Done.